# how to convert and subtract dates, times in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, python-dateutil

I have the following date/time:

> 2011-09-27 13:42:16

I need to convert it to:

> 9/27/2011 13:42:16

I also need to be able to subtract one date from another and get the result in HH:MM:SS format. I have tried to use the dateutil.parser.parse function, and it parses the date fine but sadly it doesn't seem to get the time correctly. I also tried to use another method I found on stackoverflow that uses "time", but I get an error that time is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`datetime`'s `strptime` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '2011-09-27 13:42:16'
result = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You were lucky, as I had that above line written for a project of mine.

To print it back out, try `strftime`:

```
print result.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I guess you should use '**%d**' (day of the month as a decimal number [01,31]) instead of '**%j**' (day of the year as a decimal number [001,366]) to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import dateutil.parser as dateparser

mydate = dateparser.parse("2011-09-27 13:42:16",fuzzy=True)
print(mydate.strftime('%m/%d/%Y T%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

and

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

(And the rest of the `datetime` module.)